# Communication between content script and chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and having trouble with the communication between the injected content script and the background page.  I can pass the selected element to the content script, but a test response I'm trying to send back to the extension is not being received. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious, but I'm not finding it.

**devtools.js**

```
var panels = chrome.devtools.panels;

var panel = panels.elements.createSidebarPane("Field Info",
function(sidebar) {
    // sidebar initialization code here
    sidebar.setPage("fields.html")
});

panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(){
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("setSelectedElement($0)",
    { useContentScriptContext: true });
});
```

**contentscript.js**

```
function setSelectedElement(el) {    
    console.log(el);  //Shows up
    window.postMessage({
        name: "abcde"
    });
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(devToolsConnection) {
    // assign the listener function to a variable so we can remove it later
    var devToolsListener = function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        // Inject a content script into the identified tab
        log(message);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId,
            { file: message.scriptToInject });
    }
    // add the listener
    devToolsConnection.onMessage.addListener(devToolsListener);

    devToolsConnection.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
         devToolsConnection.onMessage.removeListener(devToolsListener);
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    log(message);
});

function log(message){
    console.log(message);
}
```

Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: window.postMessage is for a page script (the code inserted in a `<script>` element). Content scripts can use chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

Comment: That was it!  If you want to make it an answer I'll give you the credit you deserve.